# Do this cURL in PHP

Tags: php, curl, operating-system

how can this be done in PHP

```
curl -I http://www.google.com | grep "Server:"
```

and is it possible to just echo OS like Linux Or windows of site , like web server is echoed using curl

My Try

```
<?
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://google.com");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$data = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $data  ;

?>
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the [PHP cURL documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or the [PHP pattern matching documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)?

Comment: i cant really figure it out tough thats why i came here @Leigh

Comment: At least show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource                                                                                                                                
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options                                                                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser                                                                                                                       
$result = curl_exec($ch);

/* Curl returns multiple headers, if the last action required multiple                                                                                       
 * requests, e.g. when doing Digest authentication. Only parse the                                                                                           
 * headers of the latest response. */
preg_match_all('/(^|\r\n\r\n)(HTTP\/)/', $result, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$startOfHeaders = $matches[2][count($matches[2]) - 1][1];
$endOfHeaders = strpos($result, "\r\n\r\n", $startOfHeaders);
$headers = substr($result, $startOfHeaders, $endOfHeaders - $startOfHeaders);
$headers = preg_split("/\r?\n/", $headers);
foreach ($headers as $headerLine) {
  if (preg_match('|^Server:\s+(.+)|', $headerLine, $m)) {
    var_dump($m[1]);
  }
}

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources                                                                                                         
curl_close($ch);
```

Basically this is an extract from [the Horde_Http library](http://www.horde.org/libraries/Horde_Http). Specifically [the Curl request](https://github.com/horde/horde/blob/master/framework/Http/lib/Horde/Http/Request/Curl.php) and [the Curl response](https://github.com/horde/horde/blob/master/framework/Http/lib/Horde/Http/Response/Curl.php) handlers.

It is somewhat more complex than what you did with your "grep" command but it looked as though you want to analyse the response headers. That is why I left the somewhat more complex header analysis in the code.

Comment: anything you can say about my second question i mentioned?

Comment: Identifying the OS is not really reliable. But often the default settings of the web server will allow you to extract the OS. See [link](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.38)